# Scraping table with JSOUP issue

Tags: android, iterator, web-scraping, jsoup

I am using JSOUP to scrape data from a table on  a site that contains a name of the player and stats. I am able to scrape the name with success but when I run my iterato rthru th erow It is always picking up the same stats for each player

Any idea?

Site source:

```
<tr id="plyr22" class="pncPlayerRow playerTableBgRow0"><td class="playertableData">1</td><td class="playertablePlayerName" id="playername_22" style=""><a href="" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc" instance="_ppc" fpopHeight="357px" fpopWidth="490px" tab="null" leagueId="0" playerId="22" teamId="-2147483648" cache="true">Kobe Bryant</a>, LAL&nbsp;SG<a href="" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc" instance="_ppc" fpopHeight="357px" fpopWidth="490px" tab="1" leagueId="0" playerId="22" teamId="-2147483648" cache="true"><img src="http://g.espncdn.com/s/fbalm/12/images/icons/sml/news_recent.png" height="12" width="15" border="0" style="margin:0 6px 0 6px" title="Recent News" /></a></td><td class="sectionLeadingSpacer"></td><td class="playertableData">0.63</td><td class="playertableData">2.41</td><td class="playertableData">1.44</td><td class="playertableData">1.29</td><td class="playertableData">2.82</td><td class="playertableData">1.84</td><td class="playertableData">0.18</td><td class="playertableData">4.81</td><td class="playerTableSpacerCell"></td><td class="playertableData sortedCell">15.41</td></tr><tr id="plyr167" class="pncPlayerRow playerTableBgRow1"><td class="playertableData">2</td><td class="playertablePlayerName" id="playername_167" style=""><a href="" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc" instance="_ppc" fpopHeight="357px" fpopWidth="490px" tab="null" leagueId="0" playerId="167" teamId="-2147483648" cache="true">Joe Johnson</a>, Atl&nbsp;SG, SF<a href="" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc" instance="_ppc" fpopHeight="357px" fpopWidth="490px" tab="2" leagueId="0" playerId="167" teamId="-2147483648" cache="true"><img src="http://g.espncdn.com/s/fbalm/12/images/icons/sml/video_breaking.png" height="11" width="19" border="0" style="margin:0 6px 0 6px" title="Breaking Video" /></a></td><td class="sectionLeadingSpacer"></td><td class="playertableData">-0.62</td><td class="playertableData">1.70</td><td class="playertableData">3.41</td><td class="playertableData">0.41</td><td class="playertableData">1.48</td><td class="playertableData">0.79</td><td class="playertableData">0.04</td><td class="playertableData">2.27</td><td class="playerTableSpacerCell"></td><td class="playertableData sortedCell">9.47</td></tr><tr id="plyr265" class="pncPlayerRow playerTableBgRow0"><td
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException,
        InterruptedException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println(title);
    int tdCount = 1;
    String name = null;
    Double stat1 = null;
    Double stat2 = null;
    Double stat3 = null;
    Double stat4 = null;
    Double stat5 = null;
    Double stat6 = null;
    Double stat7 = null;
    Double stat8 = null;
    Double stat9 = null;
    Double stat10 = null;

    Iterator<Element> trSIter = doc.select("table.playerTableTable")
            .iterator();
    while (trSIter.hasNext()) {
        Element trEl = trSIter.next().child(0);
        Elements tdEls = trEl.children();
        Iterator<Element> tdIter = tdEls.select("tr").iterator();
        boolean firstRow = true;
        while (tdIter.hasNext()) {

            Element tr = (Element) tdIter.next();
            if (firstRow) {
                firstRow = false;
                continue;
            }

            while (tdIter.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println("============================");
                Element tdEl = tdIter.next();
                name = tdEl.getElementsByClass("playertablePlayerName")
                        .text();
                System.out.println("Name: " + name);

                // System.out.println(tdEl);
                Elements tdsEls = tdEl.select("td.playertableData");
                Iterator<Element> columnIt = tdsEls.iterator();
                boolean firstRow1 = true;
                while (columnIt.hasNext()) {

                    Element td = (Element) columnIt.next();
                    if (firstRow1) {
                        firstRow1 = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                    while (columnIt.hasNext()) {

                        Element column = columnIt.next();
                        switch (tdCount++) {

                        case 1:
                            stat1 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            stat2 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            stat3 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            stat4 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            stat5 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            stat6 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            stat7 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            stat8 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            stat9 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            stat10 = Double.parseDouble(column.text());
                            break;
                        }

                        // System.out.print(column.className()+":"+column.text()+",");
                        System.out.print("stat1: " + stat1 + " stat2: "
                                + stat2 + " stat3: " + stat3 + " stat4: "
                                + stat4 + " stat5: " + stat5 + " stat6: "
                                + stat6 + " stat7: " + stat7 + " stat8: "
                                + stat8 + " stat9: " + stat9 + " stat10: "
                                + stat10);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();

            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

My OutPut

## Player Rater - Free Fantasy Basketball -  ESPN

Name: Kobe Bryant, LAL SG

## stat1: 2.41 stat2: null stat3: null stat4: null stat5: null stat6: null stat7: null stat8: null stat9: null stat10: nullstat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: null stat4: null stat5: null stat6: null stat7: null stat8: null stat9: null stat10: nullstat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: null stat5: null stat6: null stat7: null stat8: null stat9: null stat10: nullstat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: null stat6: null stat7: null stat8: null stat9: null stat10: nullstat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: null stat7: null stat8: null stat9: null stat10: nullstat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: null stat8: null stat9: null stat10: nullstat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: null stat9: null stat10: nullstat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: null stat10: null

Name: Joe Johnson, Atl SG, SF

## stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: nullstat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41

Name: Andre Iguodala, Phi SF, SG

## stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41

Name: James Harden, OKC SG

## stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41

Name: Monta Ellis, GS PG, SG

## stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41

Name: Kevin Martin, Hou SG

## stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41stat1: 2.41 stat2: 1.44 stat3: 1.29 stat4: 2.82 stat5: 1.84 stat6: 0.18 stat7: 4.81 stat8: 15.41 stat9: 1.7 stat10: 3.41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to reset `tdCount` when moving on to next row.

Comment: Also each player is getting each stst 10 times?